# Why are IP cameras giving lower FPS when accessed using two threads as compared to when accessed using two processes (linux)?

Tags: linux, multithreading, process, ip-camera

I am getting 210 frames per second from my two IP cameras (connected to two network ports on my computer) if I run two separate processes for each camera. When the cameras are accessed using a single process that creates two threads, one for each camera, then the FPS from each cameras fluctuates between 150 to 200. Parameters for both cases are same (frame width = 1320; frame height = 120; shutter time = 1.0 ms).

Why could this be happening? I think the two threads are sharing the quota of network resources assigned to one process but I am not sure what resources are becoming the bottleneck. How can I achieve 210 fps from both cameras in multi-threaded case? I am using Linux CENTOS 6.4.

PS: I have tried a third method in which I accessed one camera in the main (parent) process and another in the child process created using fork() and it gave me 210 fps on both the cameras. However, creating child process does not suit my needs. I need a solution for the case where threads of a single process are accessing the camera.

PPS: I have set net.core.rmem_max, net.core.rmem_default, net.core.wmem_max, and net.core.wmem_default to 1048576 in /etc/sysctl.conf. Their value was 131072 before changes. This change helped me with something else but not with this problem.

Comment: It could be any shared resource.  Without the actual code it's impossible to really help.

Comment: @AndrewHenle The code just consists of calling camera library functions to open camera, then set width, height, shutter, fps, and brightness and then grabbing frames from the camera in a loop. In the multi-threaded case two threads are doing the exact same thing. The only difference between the source code of two cases is that I am creating two threads using pthread_create() in one of them.